# How can i return a value from a callback function to the caller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, return

How can i make this little function "imageExists" return wether the ajax request was successful or not?

```
function imageExists(path){
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'HEAD',
        error:
            function(){
                return false;
            },
        success:
            function(){
                return true;
            }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'll have to use synchronous mode and use a separate a variable for storing the return value.

```
function imageExists(path){
    var isSuccess;
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'HEAD',
        async: false,
        error:
            function(){
                isSuccess = false;
                return false;
            },
        success:
            function(){
                isSuccess = true;
                return true;
            }
    });
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, works perjekt, didn't know that the callback function can access variables from the caller function, or like in this case from the callers, caller ...

Comment: Async false is not recommended though

Answer (score 4):

You're going to be returning the result of the AJAX call either in the `success` function or in the `error` function, so whatever function should be called next should be called from that point.

Because an AJAX request is asynchronous (I'd advise not making it a blocking synchronous call), you make the request but don't know when it will return; it'll call you when it returns, so you just need to provide it something to call.

```
function imageExists(path){
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'HEAD',
        error:
            function(){
                iveReturned(false);
            },
        success:
            function(){
                iveReturned(true);
            }
    });   
}

function iveReturned(result) {
    // code here to do something following AJAX response.
}
```

Comment: Yeah – the caller returns whatever it's going to before the callback is fired.

Comment: only if its async... if not it will halt execution until it returns.

Comment: @CrazyDart - that's exactly what I said :)

Comment: thank you! im my case it was essential, that the value comes back to the caller ...

Answer (score 1):

Create a var to hold the response on a global level, then set async to false.  You need to then set that var in the success or error function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function imageExists(path){
myVar = null;
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: 'HEAD',
    error:
        function(){
            myVar = false;
        },
    success:
        function(){
            myVar = true;
        },
    async: false
}); 
}
```